# Is there any benefit of using Helm installation method while installing OpenEBS?

Tags: kubernetes, storage, openebs, kubernetes-helm

If the installation of OpenEBS can be completed with a single command, why would a developer use helm install ? (It is probably more a helm benefits question). I'd like to understand the additional benefits OpenEBS charts can present to a helm user, if any.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you're looking at the two current supported options for [OpenEBS installation](https://docs.openebs.io/docs/next/installation.html) and noting that the helm install section is much larger with more steps than the operator-based install option. If so, note that the helm section has two sub-sections - you only need one or the other and the one that uses the [stable helm charts repo](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/openebs) is just a single command. But one might still wonder why install helm in the first place.

One of the main [advantages of helm](https://platform9.com/blog/kubernetes-helm-why-it-matters/) is the availability of standard, reusable charts for a wide range of applications. This is including but not limited to the [official charts repo](https://hub.kubeapps.com/). Relative to pure kubernetes descriptors, helm charts are easier to pass parameters into since they work as templates from which kubernetes descriptor files are generated.

Often the level of parameterisation that you get from templating is needed to ensure that an app can be installed to lots of different clusters and provide the full range of installation options that the app needs. Things like turning on or off certain permissions or pointing at storage. Different apps need different levels of configurability.

If you look at the OpenEBS non-helm deployment descriptor at https://openebs.github.io/charts/openebs-operator-0.7.0.yaml, you'll see it defines a list of resources. The same resources defined in https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/openebs/templates  Within the non-helm version the number of replicas for maya-apiserver is set at 1. To change this, you'd need to download the file and edit it or change it in your running kubernetes. With the helm version it's one of a range of parameters that you can set at install time (https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/openebs/values.yaml#L19) as options on the `helm install` command